# How to find Jack on my Animal Crossing island?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

So Jack is supposed to be the island between 5 P.M and Midnight by Resident Services, but he's not there. I've tried look everywhere, including going into and out of buildings, restarted the game and updated to the latest version, but still can't find him.

Comment: If you solved your own problem, feel free to post an answer to your own question as other people may need the same information. Don't edit the question.

Comment: @pinckerman Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I need upgrade to version [1.11.1a](https://animalcrossingworld.com/2021/10/how-to-fix-animal-crossing-new-horizons-halloween-event-not-appearing-in-2021/).

At first, the software was saying it was up to date, but after creating a Nintendo account and restarting, it updated and I found him.